# Error installing JSON on Gem Bundle Install

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to install a Ruby Gem Bundle on OSX. It is failing when trying to install the the json package. What does this error mean, how can I try to fix it and complete the bundle install?

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install json -v '1.7.7' succeeds before bundling.
MacBook-Pro:ticle_engine Stu$ gem install json -v '1.7.7'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/Stu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/Stu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160518-37614-1sz34p0.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/Stu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/Stu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                          ^
/Users/Stu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/intern.h:797:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
    ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' [-Wint-conversion]
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
      ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate I believe, the version I'm trying to install of JSON is not compatible with the Ruby version I'm running. I updated due to some issues with Open SSL install on the correct version.